# Wrong render for a component depending of JavaScript with NET8 Blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor, .net-8.0

I'm creating a new website with Blazor Web App with `NET8`. Out of the box, Visual Studio creates 2 projects for the `Interactive Mode Auto`, one for *server* and another one for *client*.

I created a repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorNet8Test) with the full solution.

I created a component with NET7 to display a select with images and the source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorImageSelect). The component is working just fine in a Blazor Web Assembly based on NET7.

Now, I want to use the same component in the Blazor Web App with `NET8`. I added the component to the client project and in the *App.razor* in the server project the required CSS and the JavaScript.

Then, I created a Razor page, marked as `@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveAuto]`, to display a select using the `ImageSelect`. When I open this page, I get this error

> InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.

[image]

So, in the ImageSelect component, I call the JSInterop in order to display the select with this code that raises the error above.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
        Id = "imageselect-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    if (Config == null)
        Config = new Config() { };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CssClass))
        Config.MainCss += " " + CssClass;

    var dotNetObjectRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
    JSModule = new ImageSelectJsInterop(JSRuntime);
    await JSModule.Setup(dotNetObjectRef, Id, Config);
}
```

So, I remove this code and I added this code as the screenshot suggests:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
        Id = "imageselect-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    if (Config == null)
        Config = new Config() { };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CssClass))
        Config.MainCss += " " + CssClass;

    var dotNetObjectRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
    JSModule = new ImageSelectJsInterop(JSRuntime);
    await JSModule.Setup(dotNetObjectRef, Id, Config);

    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

Now, the render of the component has a funny behaviour. It renders the `select` with images (on the left side of the following screenshot) but also displays another `select` only with the text (on the right).

[image]

At this point, my questions are:

- in what project can I use components with JavaScritp (server or client?)
- how can I use a component that requires JavaScript?

Comment: Question for you first: Do you know what the `bool firstRender` parameter is for?

Comment: yes, although I check if it is the `firstRender` and I run the configuration, the result is the same.

Comment: Hard to help - the code you have shared does not check firstRender, so if that is your code, you need to change it - if it's not your code, please update it. It seems like your component is rendering twice, and one is being configured - but we can't see your code

Comment: The `firstRender` is here https://github.com/erossini/BlazorNet8Test/blob/9d63d06d0d7d46892fb5abcff9b815716f9769af/Imageselect/ImageSelect.razor#L54

Comment: Exactly, apparently the component is rendered twice without a reason because in NET7 is working fine.

Comment: Does it duplicate if you set the `Id` on the ImageSelect in the markup e.g. on the Counter page `<ImageSelect id="is-test1"...` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. The `Id` is generated from the component itself and it is a guid

Comment: Yes,  and it renders the select before generating the ID and then calls your JS passing it an ID that hasn't been rendered yet,  making me question what happens if the ID is set before it renders

Comment: @MisterMagoo you are right. I have just tested it and it is working fine. Thank you so much for your help